# .htaccess password protection not working with ErrorDocument 401

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have file `.htpasswd` under `/demo/.htpasswd` and having the following code

```
admin:71.HeoDicWfCM
```

And i have one more folder **/demo/fb/** and here i have .htaccess file with following code

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "Secured Area" 
AuthUserFile "/demo/.htpasswd" 
require valid-user 
ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"
```

I am getting the popup, but when i enter username and password it shows 404 page

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create user at all.  Seems like your path of htpasswd is incorrect

Try to find full path using following code.

```
<?php
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";
echo "<p>Full path to a .htpasswd file in this dir: " . $dir . "/.htpasswd" . "</p>";
?>
```

Use full path of htpasswd in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

It means your user is not found, you need to craete this user before you can use it.

Comment: Where i need to create please ?

Comment: in `/etc/passwd`